# Best way to implement SQL "MERGE INTO" command with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, upsert

I want to do a conditional upsert with 2 pandas dataframes - analogous to the [merge into](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/) SQL function. For each row in the source dataframe, if the index doesn't exist, insert it into the destination dataframe. If the index does exist, check secondary conditions. If conditions are met, update the existing row.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'index':'1st','checkval':2,'storeval':'elephant'},
                    {'index':'2nd','checkval':7,'storeval':'giraffe'}]).set_index('index')

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'index':'1st','checkval':3,'storeval':'hippopotamus'},
                    {'index':'3rd','checkval':4,'storeval':'seagull'}]).set_index('index')
```

Here is what df1 looks like

```
        checkval    storeval
index       
1st     2           elephant
2nd     7           giraffe
```

Here is what df2 looks like

```
     checkval   storeval
index       
1st     3       hippopotamus
3rd     4       seagull
```

Here is a brute force way of doing what I describe:

```
for ind2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    found = False
     for ind1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        if ind2 == ind1:
            #Index matched
            found = True
            if row2['checkval'] > row1['checkval']:
                #Conditions met, updating existing row
                df1.loc[ind1] = row2
    if not found:
        # Row not already in df, insert
        df1 = df1.append(row2)
```

The output is:

```
    checkval    storeval
index       
1st     3   hippopotamus
2nd     7   giraffe
3rd     4   seagull
```

However, i would love to find some kind of builtin function like

```
df1.merge(d2, how = 'left', conditions = lambda df1,df2: df2['checkval']>df1['checkval'])
```

or something like that. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to make improvements over the 'brute force' method?

Answer (score 1):

try not to create unnecessary loops in pandas, this slows down and messes up the code

I think we can use [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) sorting previously:

```
new_df = df1.append(df2).sort_values('checkval').groupby(level=0).last()
#new_df = df1.append(df2).sort_values('checkval').groupby(level='index').last()
```

---

**Alternatives:**

```
new_df = df1.append(df2)
new_df = new_df.loc[~new_df.sort_values('checkval')
                           .index
                           .duplicated(keep='last'),:].sort_index()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
new_df = (df1.append(df2)
             .reset_index()
             .sort_values('checkval')
             .drop_duplicates(subset='index',keep='last')
             .set_index('index')
             .sort_index())
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
       checkval      storeval
index                        
1st           3  hippopotamus
2nd           7       giraffe
3rd           4       seagull
```